# Proving $x_{n}^2$ converges if and only if $|x_{n}|$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that given a sequence $x_{n}$, $x_{n}^2$ converges if and only if $|x_{n}|$ converges.

One way I have tried to do this is proving that the statements $|x_{n}^2-x^{*}_{1}|<\varepsilon_{1}$ for all $n>N_{1}$ and $||x_{n}|-x^{*}_{2}|<\varepsilon_{2}$ for all $n>N_{2}$ are equivalent. Unfortunately I have not had any success using this method.

I posted a question in a similar vein to this earlier, but it could be solved in a much easier way than proving the equivalence of two statements like this, and I still don't quite understand how a question like this could be solved.

If anyone could find a way of solving this question, or similar ones to it, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Both $x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are continuous on $[0,+\infty)$. The image of a convergent sequence through a continuous function is a convergent sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jack D'Aurizio points out the general result. Let me demonstrate a direct method for this particular case.

Let $x = \sqrt{y}$. Let us write
$$ |x_n^2 - y| = |x_n - x||x_n + x|. $$
I leave it as an exercise to show that there exists some $z > 0$ so that $|x_n + x| \ge z$ for all $n$ sufficiently large (ie there exists an $n_0$ so that this holds for all $n \ge n_0$). Hence we have, for $n \ge n_0$,
$$ |x_n - x| \le z^{-1} |x_n^2 - y| \to 0. $$
This proves that $\{ x_n^2 \to y \} \implies \{ x_n \to x = \sqrt{y} \}$.

For the other way, we used boundedness; I leave it as an exercise to show that there exists a $K$ so that $|x_n| \le K$ for all $n$. In the same way as above, we can then deduce from this that
$$ |x_n^2 - y| \le (K + |x|) |x_n - x| \to 0. $$
This proves that $\{ x_n \to x \} \implies \{ x_n^2 \to y = x^2 \}$.